# Prove that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ is independent of $\liminf X_n$ by analogy with events.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, limsup-and-liminf

If we had independent events $E_1, E_2,...$ we'd just say that $\tau_{\{E_n\}}$, of which $\limsup E_n$ is an element, is $\mathbb P$-trivial by Kolmogorov 0-1 Law and thus  is independent of anything.

For independent random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$, as an alternative to these:

[Prove that limsup and liminf of an independent sequence are independent of finite number of terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372651)

[Showing independence of a limsup of an independent sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448581)

can we just say that $\limsup X_n$ is something like the random variable equivalent of $\mathbb P-$ trivial and thus independent of anything? What is the random variable equivalent of $\mathbb P-$ trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Part II of Kolmogorov 0-1 Law in Williams](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303735).

Just as $\limsup E_n$ is $\mathbb P-$trivial and thus independent of any event/s, $\limsup X_n$ is constant $\mathbb P-$a.s. and thus independent of any random variable/s or $\sigma-$algebra/s.